# Access elements of a list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm completely new to JQuery and I hope to get some help from SO folks.

This snippet basically generated a random numbers and filled a list along with index values

i.e. [0 10],[1 12],[2 30]... so on

```
    function getRandomData() {
        if (data.length > 0)
            data = data.slice(1);

        // do a random walk
        while (data.length < totalPoints) {
            var prev = data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1] : 50;
            var y = prev + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
            if (y < 0)
                y = 0;
            if (y > 100)
                y = 100;
            data.push(y);
        }

        // zip the generated y values with the x values
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
            res.push([i, data[i]])
        return res;
    }
```

Can any one out there help me out with the syntax to retrieve the elements inside **data** 
which is in turn present in the **res** collection.

i.e. i want to know the random number generated each time the function **getRandomData**
is called

I hope i made it clear 
Regards

Comment: There's no jQuery here, and no apparent need to add it. JavaScript and jQuery are not synonyms. Where are `data` and `totalPoints` defined and what are they set to initially?

Comment: What is `data` and `totalPoints`?

Comment: There are just variables. data is a collection or a list. For ex : data = [] and totalPoints = 100

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
// Save the return value of the function in a variable
var arr = getRandomData();
// Print data to the console
console.log(arr)

// Print the first dataset
console.log(arr[0]) // [0, 29]
// Print only the number of the first set
console.log(arr[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var res = [
    [0, 10],
    [1, 12],
    [2, 30]
];
var x = res[0][1]; // returns 10
var y = res[1][1]; // returns 12
var z = res[2][1]; // returns 30
```

You can access any sub-arrays using this syntax:

```
array[first level index][second level index][...nth level index];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` var appears to come from outside the function scope so you could just do

```
console.log(data)
```

Though I guess you're maybe asking for the syntax as given by @MildlyInteresting ?